# php add to database if query string equals value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ig'])) {
        ******$fromig=$_GET['ig']******
        if ($fromig = 1) {
            require 'pdo-instagram.php';
            echo '<script>alert("Instagram");</script>'
        }
    } else if (isset($_GET['fb'])) {
        ******$fromfb=$_GET['ig']******
        if ($fromfb = 1) {
            require 'pdo-facebook.php';
            echo '<script>alert("Facebook");</script>'
        }
}
?>
```

Basically, I want to add in a feature to my page and it will tell me where people come from. For example:

On my Instagram profile, I will add in `http://joshmurray.eu/?ig=1` to my profile so the PHP can look at the string, and determine which table it put information in. *For this case, it will `INSERT` a timestamp into the table `instagram`*

That part I have put in stars above, I know that part is wrong but I somehow have to use the PDO version of `mysql_real_escape_string` and I'm not sure how. (I think, I'm not very good at PHP)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** I haven't selected a correct answer because none of the worked *but* this is my code that works:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "database";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO from_instagram (timestamp)
            VALUES (now())";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

I ***HAD*** to change my table name from `from-instagram` to `from_instgram` because I forgot that PHP interprates a `-` as a subtract sign so when the code is executed, it looks like I'm subtracting `from` from `instagram`.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: So, you need to insert a timstamp into database using PDO right?

Comment: You can prepare and statement and execute in PDO. It doesn't required to use mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: Could you show me how I could do this? Cheers.

Comment: Check my answer and comment if  need any help on coding.

Comment: *"I HAD to change my table name from `from-instagram` to `from_instgram`"* - No, you didn't. You just needed to surround the table name in backtick characters when using it in your query text (ref: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample, you can extend as per your requirements.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ig'])) {
    if($_GET['ig'] == 1){
        // Insert the data to table
        $tableName = 'instagram';
        // Or you may use your own external file
        if( insertData($tableName) ){
            // Data inserted
        }
    }

}
if (isset($_GET['fb'])) {
    if($_GET['fb'] == 1){
        // Insert the data to table
        $facebook = 'facebook';
        // Or you may use your own external file
        if( insertData($facebook) ){
            // Data inserted
        }
    }
}

function insertData($table){
    // Database credentials
    $hostname = 'your_host';
    $username = 'your_username';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'your_database';

    try {
        // Connect to database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // Now you are connected to database let'd do the operations
        // Instead of mysql_real_escape_string you can use a prepared statement
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO $table ( Time ) VALUES ( now() )');
        $stmt->execute();
        // If you are not using a MySQL function do this way
        // $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO instagram ( Time ) VALUES ( :Time )');
        // $stmt->execute(array(':Time' => $time )); // $time is the variable which contains the value

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this and it looked like it was working but when I looked back in the directory of the `index.php`, I saw a lot of errors repeated over and over from me refreshing the page. I have just used `mysqli` for connecting to a database now - thank you for the answer you gave me though, very detailed and easy to understand *but* my knowledge of PHP isn't great and I never knew how to fix the errors that were there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ig'])) {
        $fromig=$_GET['ig'];
        if ($fromig == 1) {
            require 'pdo-instagram.php';
            echo '<script>alert("Instagram");</script>'
        }
    } else if (isset($_GET['fb'])) {
        $fromfb=$_GET['ig'];
        if ($fromfb == 1) {
            require 'pdo-facebook.php';
            echo '<script>alert("Facebook");</script>'
        }
}
?>
```

You have to use  " == " (double equal to) in if condition.

Try my code.

Comment: This never worked - although, thanks for trying to help :)